# LP: add extra costs in the objective function for every variable which is not equal to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, regularization

I am trying to optimise an LP problem but extra costs should be added if a variable is larger than $0$.

For example, if we have the following objective function:

$$\text{minimize} \qquad 2X_1 + 3X_2 + 3X_3$$

For every $X_i$ in the solution that is not $0$ extra costs of 1 should be added to the objective function. 
So if the solution is
$X_1 = 0$
$X_2 = 2$
$X_3  = 3$
Then the total costs are $2 \cdot 0+3 \cdot 2+3 \cdot 3 + 2 = 17$
Is this possible in such a way that it remains a linear program?
And is it also possible to only add extra costs if $X_1$ or $X_2$ is not equal to $0$?

Comment: Are there nonnegativity constraints?

Comment: No the variables may be negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you want to do is often called *$L_0$ regularization*:
$$\min_{X}\quad 2X_1 + 3X_2 + 3X_3 + \|X\|_0$$
and this extra term takes you well outside the domain of linear programming (the general form of this problem is known to be NP-hard; relaxations using the $L_1$ norm are very common and are the topic of e.g. compressed sensing). Of course, if you only have a small number of variables $n$ you can brute-force a solution by trying all $2^n$ possible assignments of "zero" or "non-zero" to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when [parameterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) by the number of *non-*zero variables,

[no known algorithm](http://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/cnf-sat-feasible.pdf) is much faster than just trying

each possibility for what variables are non-zero:

Reduce from [Dominating Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set):

Each vertex is a variable, and there are no other variables. ​ For each vertex u,

let B<sub>u</sub> be the set of vertices v such that [[u,v are [adjacent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#A)] or [u,v are the same vertex]].

Minimize 0 $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ subject to, for each u, $\;\;\; 1 \: \leq \: \displaystyle\sum_{v\in B_u} v \:\:\:\:$.

One can constrain them to be non-negative and/or at-most-1

without changing which [possibilities for what variables are non-zero]

let the modified objective function's overall minimum be achieved.

However, that does not indicate anything about *the opposite* parameterization;

namely, by number of variables which *equal* zero.